# BackBarButtonItem in iOS8 can't change tintColor?

Tags: ios8, backbarbuttonitem

I have called `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:XXX]` in my AppDelegate.

But I find the backBarButtonItem doesn't change its tintColor when the other barItems have changed to right color.

Is't a bug only in iOS8 beta5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:XXXXX]]`